# vim -- search and replace function call with type field

Tags: vim, vi

I have a tricky one.

I have a bunch of function calls in my code, i.e. `getproperty(mytype)`.

I want to replace all of these with `mytype.property`

A well crafted `%s` would make life easier.

Many thanks.

Edit:

In response to comments asking for additional information:

I have a text file

```
type Foo
   property
end

func getproperty(Foo)  
 return Foo.property
end

mytype = Foo(1.2)

a = bar.baz * getproperty(mytype)

b = a * exp(getproperty(mytype)) * sqrt(getproperty(mytype))
```

etc etc

I want to clean this up by getting rid of the `getproperty` function call and accessing `mytype.property` directly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This question is tricky mostly because you haven't given us sufficient information to know what you're talking about, what you have, or what you want. Please use the EDIT button to fix this and make it less tricky.

Comment: FWIW, the comments asked for *basic* information, not "additional" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that your “`property`” and “`mytype`” are placeholders;
i.e., you want to transform

```
getproperty(mytype)
```

into

```
mytype.property
```

in general.

If your properties and types are all composed entirely of lowercase letters,

```
%s/get\([a-z]*\)(\([a-z]*\))/\2.\1/g
```

should do it. 
For example, it changes

```
getheight(barney) + getweight(fred)
```

into

```
barney.height + fred.weight
```

If they can include uppercase letters and/or digits,
make the trivially obvious changes to the regular expression. 
If they can be more complex expressions,
like `flintstone[1]` or `wilma.husband`,
try to define precisely what they can and cannot be.